# bash loop adds single quotes

Tags: bash, loops

maybe someone here can enlighten me:

function:

```
add_repo() {
  for repo in "${repos[@]}"; do
    sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists "$repo"
  done
}
```

script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash

repos=(
  "flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo"
)

source function

add_repo
```

output:

```
sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists 'flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo'
```

output without quotation on `$repo`:

```
sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

This is the desired output.

Question:
How can I quote the variable without added single quotes? I know, that `set -x` (set only for debugging) adds these single quotes to allow for better reading, but somehow the command ends after `--if-not-exists` because of the added single quotes even without `set -x`.

Comment: There is nothing in what you show that produces this `sudo flatpak ...` output. Where does it come from? Please also show the code that prints this.

Comment: That's the very purpose of the quotes. With `"$repo"`, you tell bash to pass the content of the variable `repo` as single argument to the called program. Without the quotes, you tell bash to split the content of the variable `repo` into words and pass each word as separate argument. BTW, if you would use zsh instead of bash, you would - in your concrete case - get the same effect in both cases (one parameter being passed, regardless of quotes).

Comment: edited the post to include the calling script.

Comment: @user1934428: So in this case to non quote the variable is correct because the variable includes two (separately) needed arguments for the command?

Comment: @crashfistfight In this specific case, not quoting the variable will work, but I wouldn't call it *correct*, just something you can get away with. In general, storing commands in variables (and/or single array elements) tends to cause trouble (see [BashFAQ #50: "I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)), so it would really be better to look for another way to do it.

Comment: It happens to work here, but in general, this case is handled  better by putting the arguments in an array, not into a single string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When consuming subset groups of values from a list; it is convenient to have a function or a command to pop-out needed values from list's values passed as arguments.

Here, create the `addrepos` bash script command, so it can be invoked with `sudo`, elevating privileges only once to add all repositories.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# addrepos NAME URL [ NAME URL ] ...

# While there are arguments
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
  # Pops repository name from arguments
  repo_name="${1}"
  shift
  # Pops repository URL from arguments
  repo_url="${1}"
  shift

  flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists "${repo_name}" "${repo_url}"
done
```

Make it executable:

```bash
chmod +x addrepos
```

The main script call the `addrepo` script with `sudo`:

```bash
#! /usr/bin/env bash

# repository name and url are distinct entries in the repos array
repos=(
  'flathub' 'https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo'
)

# sudo call addrepos with the content of the repos array as arguments
sudo ./addrepos "${repos[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the example! For one repo defintion  in `repos` this works as intended. If i add a second defintion, e.g. `'flathub-beta' 'https://flathub.org/beta-repo/flathub-beta.flatpakrepo'` i get this critcial error `(flatpak remote-add:2910): GLib-GIO-CRITICAL **: 21:53:02.840: g_task_get_cancellable: assertion 'G_IS_TASK (task)' failed
`.

Comment: @crashfistfight this error is unrelated to the script. Found this possibly mentioning the same error https://github.com/flathub/org.gnome.Evolution/issues/26

Comment: yeah, this is indeed a specific problem with the flathub-beta repo. I added another repo in `repos` and the script succeeded.